# How to use CAST function with JPQL Query

Tags: postgresql, casting, jpql

I am trying to use `CAST` function in `JPQL` query for converting data type from Integer to String. But I am getting `QuerySyntaxException`.

**JPQL Query**

```
@Query("select a from Alerts as a "
        + "Inner Join RoomTransfer as rt ON  a.salertActionData= cast (rt.nTransId character varying)" 
        + " where a.nalertId=?1")
public List<Alerts> transferedDetailsByAlertId(Integer nalert_id );
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'varying' near line 1
```

Can any one please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Write `CAST (rt.nTransId AS string)`

See:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions
- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-provided

Comment: I tried getting error:  `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : String `

Comment: yes it's working. I was tried capital `S` for string. can you tell why to use small `s` for `string `

Comment: @SpringUser: The answer is in the links. Please read the docs :)